# How to remove unused styles in StandardStyles.xaml?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Each new Windows 8 C# Metro project contains StandardStyles.xaml file with lot of styles and templates for various controls. Mostly I use only like 10% of them and I define lot of my own styles.

Hot to easily and safely find and/or remove all unused styles? As far as I know parsing long XAML files increases the startup time of my Windows 8 app and that's something I'd like to avoid. Or do you think I should not care about those 1800 lines of code?

Comment: If you're not sure it's an issue why don't you try it with/without the ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment in the header gives you a pretty good idea:

> ```
> This file contains XAML styles that simplify application development.
>
> These are not merely convenient, but are required by most Visual Studio project and item templates.
> Removing, renaming, or otherwise modifying the content of these files may result in a project that
> does not build, or that will not build once additional pages are added.  If variations on these
> styles are desired it is recommended that you copy the content under a new name and modify your
> private copy.
> ```

If you modify the file then add another view later on, you might be stuck with a view that is not working and you will have to then figure out which styles you need to re-add.

The overhead of this file is small and I would not worry about how it affects your startup time as almost every other XAML app will have the same overhead.

Comment: I guess the parsing overhead for the StandardStyles.xaml is acceptable and we should rather care about more time demanding issues in our apps.